# What is the CloudFoundry infrastructure?

Tags: vmware, cloud-foundry

Does anyone have any idea if CloudFoundry is based on IaaS and datacenters from VMware, or is it based on 3rd party IaaS providers such AWS EC2??

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudFoundry.com runs on VMware's own Vsphere [infrastructure](http://www.zdnet.com/vmware-tests-vsphere-resilience-with-cloud-foundry-3040093821/) and servers:

CF, though, is open source, and other providers offer their own service.

Comment: so they own their own datacenters?

Comment: I would assume exactly the same, but do you have any proof of that? Would you happen to know where i could find some reading about it?

Comment: The link in the answer is quite convincing, but you might also read      http://arstechnica.com/business/2012/04/vmware-wants-to-be-linux-of-the-cloud-touts-open-source-projects/

Answer (score 5):

Cloud Foundry is a open source Platform as a Service. It's entirely written with Ruby and the components are very loose couple. You can download Cloud Foundry source code from https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap. Cloud Foundry is a PaaS which comes on top of the IaaS layer. Now your IaaS layer can be anything (i.e. vmware vSphere, Amazon EC2, Cloudstack and etc.)

cloudfoundry.com is a hosted Cloud Foundry PaaS environment by vmware. Since this service is being given by vmware, IaaS is vmware as well. It provides a free 2 Gig storage to any user who registers. After registration, users can deploy their apps which would then become a subdomain of cloudfoundry.com (i.e. myCompanyName.cloudfoundry.com). This service is currently in Beta right now.

You can find more information on the following websites:

http://www.cloudfoundry.com

http://www.cloudfoundry.org

http://docs.cloudfoundry.com

http://support.cloudfoundry.com